# Why is scheduledLocalNotifications empty during GHUnit CLI?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm creating a bunch of `UILocalNotification` objects and adding them using `scheduleLocalNotification`. Everything works fine in my app and the GHUnit UI tests. However, when I run the same test from the command line, `scheduledLocalNotifications` array is empty.

I tried printing the `UILocalNotification` object right after creating it and it looks fine. Even if I set the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array directly, it still comes back empty.

Comment: I use GHUnit a lot, but not from the command line so I don't have an answer. Have yout ried contacting the author of GHUnit?

Comment: Nope. Cross posted in GHUnit Google Group but no response there too. I'll try to contact the author.